Minimizing overhead in IntPtr to String conversion
I have an IntPtr (representing a char*) received from a C++ DLL, and I want to convert it to a string in C#. Is Span<char>.ToString always generating a new string instance, or is there a way to avoid creating a new string when converting from IntPtr?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Additionally, the resulting string will be bound to a property in WinUI 3 XAML.
// Simulate a char* received from C++
String original = "Hello";
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(original); // Allocate as UTF-16 (char*)

try
{
    // Convert IntPtr to Span<char> and then to String
    Span<char> span = new Span<char>(ptr.ToPointer(), original.Length);
    String result = span.ToString();
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}


@user555045 People often use char* instead of void* by habit or ignorance. Though in this case, StringToHGlobalUni is documented as returning wchar_t* (or char16_t* where sizeof(wchar_t) != 2) - though as no pointer-arithmetic is being performed it's not something I'd be too concerned about if I were doing a code-review of this.

string is immutable, the runtime must guarantee it isn't changed by some rogue C++ code that took a copy of the pointer. unsafe code can break that rule, but should be avoided. If you have a lot of duplicate strings, you could Intern them...

@Jeremy Lakeman — This is the only comprehensive explanation, so won't you make it a formal answer?

I am currently studying and deepening my understanding of various concepts. Everyone's input has been very helpful. Thank you!

Have you done memory/performance profiling to confirm that this is an actual problem? How many strings are you creating per second?

@JonasH I measured memory and time by looping a conversion of 10 characters 100,000 times, and the result was between 0 to 3 ms for the 100,000 loops. I confirmed this using methods other than this question, and they all showed the same results. I didn't want to create new String instances, but I understand now that it's unavoidable.

But do you need to convert strings 100,000 times in your application? And if you do, is the 3ms it takes an actual problem? See why premature optimization is the root of all evil

Why are you manually handling strings anyway? The marshaller can do all this for you. Just declare the parameter as [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] out string yourParam. You only need to do it yourself if you need to free the pointer. Also StringToHGlobalUni should be StringToHGlobalAnsi

@Charlieface I want to make it a blittable type.

@JonasH You’re right, premature optimization should be approached with caution. Thank you.

If your C++ code is generating lots of duplicate strings, you could string.Intern() them to save memory. But I don't think that's what you're asking about.
Creating a string from any kind of memory buffer will require a copy of that string to be allocated. Using a Span<char> to help track the memory buffer shouldn't add any overhead, since a span can only exist on the stack and only really contains a pointer and length.
Since string is supposed to be immutable, the runtime must guarantee that the memory buffer can't be manipulated by some rogue C++ code that kept a copy of the memory address. While you can break that rule with unsafe code, I wouldn't recommend it.
If the memory allocation is causing a significant performance issue, then perhaps you should avoid using string at all.

Thank you for your advice.
The C++ DLL that retrieves the string is something I created myself, so it is not malicious code.
I understand that I should avoid retrieving strings from the C++ DLL whenever possible. Additionally, I realize that creating a C# string from a memory buffer inevitably requires a copy, which means that Span.ToString also results in a copy—unfortunately!
